# Android share intent vs actual Facebook integration

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, sharing

I am going to integrate "facebook sharing" into an app. Basically a timeline post with a link and an image and text.

What is the difference between an elaborate Facebook 3.0 integration vs using the Android OS' share intent with certain parameters, where the latter allows users to choose between apps such as Facebook and it just works if the app is configured to use that intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this Facebook [bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/332619626816423/), I guess you have to do it with the Facebook SDK.

Since they only allow posting a link with the share intent.

Answer (score 3):

The only difference will be a one line of code that will work with thousands of different app (and other social network) Vs bloating your app with Facebook SDK, hours of work, pain, bug for a less clean result.

;-)

Edit: 
The Android Intent will also allow people to share on Twitter, Google Plus, and other websites if they don't like Facebook.

Comment: hah, true. I have dealt with various facebook SDK iterations and facebook for android 3.0 is by far the most convoluted. I wasn't sure if the simple OS sharing feature still worked