# Do any widely used Android apps have Facebook sharing with pre-populated text field?

Tags: android, android-facebook, shareactionprovider

I'm creating an Android app for a small business owner.  I've implemented social sharing with a ShareActionProvider, and I have discovered that Facebook *purposely* does not allow apps to pre-populate posts.  The user must enter their own text.  (See [this S.O. post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545254) and then [this S.O. post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200851) ).

Multiple S.O. answers have indicated that by using the Facebook SDK, it is possible to achieve this result (pre-populating Facebook posts).

On the other hand, I learned that Facebook has [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill] (a policy) against doing this.

My questions are:
1) Is this really possible? 
   If so, how difficult is it to implement compared to the SharActionProvider?

2) Are there any popular or major apps whose Facebook sharing feature pre-populates text for the user?

3) Has Facebook been known to crack down on this policy?  What has been their action towards people who break this policy?

This is the first Android app I've created and the first project I've done in 'real life'.  I'm trying to figure out if adding this feature would be worth it for his business.  He indicated he would like this feature to create an easy way to users to share content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my app I share the quotes from various famous personalities to social media. I have integrated Facebook SDK to enable user share it on their wall. I have not faced any crackdown from Facebook. App is being used over by 5K people as of now.

So to answer your questions,

1. Yes, it is possible. Not difficult to implement
2. I am not aware of other popular apps that use this feature
3. No crackdown or action from FB

This is what I do to share the quote on user's FB wall.

```html
public void onClickFBShare(View view) {
  quotview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MainText);
  line = quotview.getText().toString(); //converting the text to String
  Intent FBIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SHAREHELPER");
  FBIntent.putExtra("quote", line);
  startActivity(FBIntent);
 }
```

The code to post the content is in Sharehelper.Java

```html
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.content.pm.Signature;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;
import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton;
import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton.UserInfoChangedCallback;


public class ShareHelper extends ActionBarActivity{

     private LoginButton loginBtn;
     private Button updateStatusBtn;
  
     private TextView fbquote;
     
     private TextView userName;
  
     private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
  
     private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
     
     private String message;
     
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         
      // Add code to print out the key hash
         try {
             PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                     "com.facebook.samples.hellofacebook", 
                     PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
             for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                 MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                 md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                 Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
                 }
         } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

         } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

         }

         
         Intent intent = getIntent();
      
      message = intent.getStringExtra("quote");     
    
  
         uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, statusCallback);
         uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  
         setContentView(R.layout.sharehelper_activity);
     
         fbquote = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.FbTextView);
         fbquote.setText(message);
         
         userName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_name);
         loginBtn = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fb_login_button);
         loginBtn.setUserInfoChangedCallback(new UserInfoChangedCallback() {
             @Override
             public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) {
                 if (user != null) {
                     userName.setText("Hello, " + user.getName());
                 } else {
                     userName.setText("You are not logged");
                 }
             }
         });
  
         updateStatusBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update_status);
         updateStatusBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
              postStatusMessage();
             }
         });
  
         buttonsEnabled(false);
     }
  
     private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
         @Override
         public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                 Exception exception) {
             if (state.isOpened()) {
                 buttonsEnabled(true);
                 Log.d("FacebookSampleActivity", "Facebook session opened");
             } else if (state.isClosed()) {
                 buttonsEnabled(false);
                 Log.d("FacebookSampleActivity", "Facebook session closed");
             }
         }
     };
  
     public void buttonsEnabled(boolean isEnabled) {
         updateStatusBtn.setEnabled(isEnabled);
     }
  
    
     public void postStatusMessage() {
         if (checkPermissions()) {
             Request request = Request.newStatusUpdateRequest(
                     Session.getActiveSession(), message,
                     new Request.Callback() {
                         @Override
                         public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                             if (response.getError() == null)
                                 Toast.makeText(ShareHelper.this,
                                         "Quote Shared successfully",
                                         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         }
                     });
             request.executeAsync();
         } else {
             requestPermissions();
         }
     }
  
     public boolean checkPermissions() {
         Session s = Session.getActiveSession();
         if (s != null) {
             return s.getPermissions().contains("publish_actions");
         } else
             return false;
     }
  
     public void requestPermissions() {
         Session s = Session.getActiveSession();
         if (s != null)
             s.requestNewPublishPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(
                     this, PERMISSIONS));
     }
  
     @Override
     public void onResume() {
         super.onResume();
         uiHelper.onResume();
         buttonsEnabled(Session.getActiveSession().isOpened());
     }
  
     @Override
     public void onPause() {
         super.onPause();
         uiHelper.onPause();
     }
  
     @Override
     public void onDestroy() {
         super.onDestroy();
         uiHelper.onDestroy();
     }
  
     @Override
     public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
         super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
         uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     }
  
     @Override
     public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedState) {
         super.onSaveInstanceState(savedState);
         uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(savedState);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to prefill the data, however it's really not recommended and support for it is non-existent. Facebook have explicitly highlighted it in their terms.

> Pre-fill the user message parameter with any content the user didn't enter themselves, even if they can edit or delete that content before sharing. This applies to posts, comments, photo captions, and photo album captions.

While I've not seen Facebook crack down on it personally that doesn't mean that should do it. If it was a grey area you'd have grounds to fight a Facebook fight (i.e. removing a business page, blocking API access...) however it's very clear about not doing it.